# Json problems using Angular2 and Net Core Web Api

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have trouble receiving a request containing JSON on the  server side. Somehow, username and password don't get properly mapped to the User object.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

here is the model:

```
 public class User
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a basic login action in my api controller recieving a request:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public ActionResult Login([FromBody] User user)
    {
        if (user.username == null || user.password == null)
            return StatusCode(400);

        string result = _tokenHelper.GenerateToken(user.username);

        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

and an Angular 2 service sending the request

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { /*HTTP_PROVIDERS, */ Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    jwtToken: any;

    constructor(public authHttp: AuthHttp) { }

    //jwtHeader = new Headers({
    //    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    //    "alg": "HS256",
    //    "typ": "JWT"
    //});

    Login(username: string, password: string) {
        this.authHttp.post('/api/login',
            JSON.stringify({
                "username:": username,
                "password:": password
            })
            //,{ headers: this.jwtHeader }
        ).subscribe(data => this.jwtToken = data,
            () => console.log(this.jwtToken));

        return this.jwtToken;
    }
```

EDIT 1:

I have debugged the program and null User object gets to the action on the server even though I see the request has more or less the right body. Only the parameters are in the wrong order, password being first for some unknown reason.

[image: here you can see that the request actually happens and that it returns 400 in accordance with my control code]

Comment: How do you know the problem is sending the request to the server side? Can you include a screenshot of your network tab while making this request (and the response)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to send without doing `JSON.stringify` in your angular2 method? Stringify send it as a string and not as an json object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, that did not help.

Comment: I believe you send your message as { username: x, password: y } in fiddler. could you also try to send as { user: { username: x, password: y } }?

Comment: i am sending it through the actual angular app. sending through fiddler gives me 415, bad format  for some reason

Comment: did you also removed `:` from "username:" and "password:"?

Comment: if you get bad request add `content-type: text/json` in the header. this should solve

Comment: sorry it should be `content-type: application/json`

Comment: Yes, i am so dumb! I forgot the `:` in there. Now I am getting an empty response back to the client. Gonna investigate that now! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do not forget to mark as answer if possible. Thanks